# Getting error when returning a dereferenced iterator

Tags: c++

I'm trying to return a dereferenced iterator in my code and it's giving me the following error:

```
`Attempt to copy-construct an iterator from a singular iterator.`
```

The piece of code that is giving me this error is the following one:

```
Autor Cjt_Autors::get_autor(const string & nom) {
    map<string, Autor, compare>::iterator it = autors.find(nom);
    if (it != autors.end())
        return it->second;
    return Autor();
}
```

The error is happening in runtime just when I'm compiling my code on g++ with the following parameters: `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG -ansi -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-sign-compare -std=c++0x`

I tried running it without the -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG parameter and it worked, but it's a must on my project so I don't know how to fix this. However, the function returned what it had to in run-time.

I have tried the same code on Windows with Visual Studio and it was working flawlessly. I hope somebody can find the flaw in my code that keeps making it break, as I have been trying to find a solution for it for hours and I don't know how to proceed.

The problem is not dereferencing the iterator itself, as I have just tried putting this before the return:
`cout << it->second.get_ntextos() << endl;`
And it prints the value correctly, so the crash is definitely happening on the return.

EDIT:Compare function used in the map.

```
struct compare
{
    bool operator()(const Autor& a, const Autor& b) const {
        return a.get_nom() < b.get_nom();
    }
};
```

Class structure:

```
class Cjt_Autors
{
private:
    map<string, Autor, compare> autors; //Ordenat per nom
    map<string, Autor, compare>::iterator autorTriat;
    bool bTriat;
    map<string, int> countRef;

    static bool check_inicials(const map<string, Autor, compare>::iterator & ita, const string & ref);
```

There are lots of public functions. If you guys want me to post them I'll do it as well.
The function is called with the following parameter:
"Mario Bunge" without the quotation marks.

Comment: I'll bet that the `compare` function is messing up the map.

Comment: @PeteBecker in which way? I'll update posting the compare function.

Comment: What would be most useful is a [mcve].

Comment: Think you're looking in the wrong direction, Swaggaaa. A `std::map` that's keyed by `std::string` is provided a comparator function that compares `Autor`, not `std::string`. This is pretty odd behaviour that won't compile. I'd fix this first and see if it makes the bizzarro iterator message goes away.

Comment: @user4581301 sorry if I didn't explain myself correctly, as the error is happening in runtime not during compiling. However if I compile it without `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` the code works perfectly. 

I don't quite understand what you say regarding the key as I'm doing a find with the specified key and it's being found. However when it has to return the actual class `Autor`, the program crashes with the previously specified error.

Comment: Can't understand how you got that to compile. Here's a quick hack cut of what I think you've got and what should happen: http://ideone.com/2nWLfg

Comment: c++0x is depreciated, give c++11 a try. There might be an incompatibility between c++0x and libc++

Comment: @user4581301 The class structure shows how it's defined in the header. In the constructor it's declared as such: map<string, Autor, compare> autors(); (Notice the parenthesis in the end).

Comment: @CemKalyoncu I tried compiling it with c++11, same error. The only parameter that saves me from getting it is the D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG one, but It's a must in my project.

Comment: @user4581301 just to make it more clear:


`Cjt_Autors::Cjt_Autors() {`
    `autors = map<string, Autor, compare>();`
    `autorTriat = map<string, Autor, compare>::iterator();`
    `countRef = map<string, int>();`
    `bTriat = false;`
`}`

Comment: Two points: 1. `autors = map<string, Autor, compare>();` is unncecessary. The compiler did this for you already when it set up the object before entering the constructor's body. 2. That shouldn't make a bit of difference. `std::map` is going to call the comparator with `std::string` because the key type is `std::string`. The comparator accepts only `Autor`, so you should get a type mismatch and a failed build.